# Nvidia Geforce 680 GTX - Glitches on screen

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have an Nvidia Geforce 680 GTX and installed the prob. driver Ubuntu showed me![Screenshot1]. I have the problem that if e. g. I have to scroll down a large document I get glitches. I looks like some lines are overlaying or rendered to late. It's kinda hard for me to describe it since I don't know how to explain it in English ;-)

Maybe it's just a setting in the Nvidia XServer? The screen is connected via HDMI. Could ths be the problem.

The problem exists in Unity and Gnom3.

Here is some more information about the system:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64 bit)
- Memory 16 GB
- Intel Core i7-3770K CPU@3.50GHz x 8
- Graphic GeForce GTX 680/PCIe/SSE2

I really would appreciate if someone could help me. This is quite annoying. If you need any further information I will try to provide them.

Thanks in advance!

Mark

[image]

Comment: What version of `nvidia` drivers are you currently using? It's not clear from the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check on Nvidia's [Unix Driver Archive](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html) or [Driver Downloads](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) which version of their drivers support your card (`GeForce GTX 680`). In this case it's `304.1170` and `331.20`.
2. Check on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) if this package is provided for `12.04`. If not, then check for it in the `proposed` repo (see [how to search for proposed updates on ubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400944/how-to-search-for-proposed-updates-on-ubuntu-com) and [BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)). Both versions are packaged for `Precise` in `updates` or `proposed` repositories: [“nvidia-graphics-drivers-304-updates”](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304-updates) and [“nvidia-graphics-drivers-331-updates”](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331-updates).
3. You can enable `updates` repo in `Synaptic > Settings > Repos > Updates > Updates` and then install the latest `nvidia-304` (actually `304.116` is available). You can use `Additional Drivers` to enable this driver. Prior to doing so, you may want to `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-304`.
4. If that doesn't work, you can enable `proposed` repo in `Synaptic > Settings > Repos > Updates > Proposed` and then install the latest `nvidia-331`. You can use `Additional Drivers` to enable this driver.
5. After installing the necessary driver, sometimes it's necessary to run `sudo nvidia-xconfig`. See [NVIDIA X Server Settings lost on every reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379483/nvidia-x-server-settings-lost-on-every-reboot).
6. Reboot.