# Nvidia X server settings go default after boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, colors, nvidia-settings, additional-drivers

Okay, just for your information , I am a complete newbie when it comes to Ubuntu. Installed it today!

Everything, so far seems great however I have stumbled upon an issue which is that the Nvidia X server is unable to keep its altered settings after a fresh boot. Why is that?!

All what was required , was to change the Digital Vibrancy setting to the max but it keeps going back to 0 after each boot.

The Ubuntu version that is used is 15.10 and the Nvidia Driver, installed is the latest and the tested version.

There maybe a solution here [NVIDIA X Server Settings lost on every reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379483/nvidia-x-server-settings-lost-on-every-reboot) and I tried my best to do that which was prescribed but wasn't able to resolve my issue.

Please kindly help me! Don't let Ubuntu leave a sour taste for me.