# Nvidia settings get reset every time I open NVIDIA X Server

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu

I'm on Kubuntu 15.10 with the Nvidia Proprietary driver. But whenever I save the Nvidia settings, it only saves temporarily. Everything gets reset the next time I open the settings. This happens to both, the resolution settings and the color settings.

Comment: exact error message? Screen shot? What nvidia graphics card you have?

Comment: @Ashu I don't get any error message. It just gets reset every time I open it. I have a GTX 660M

Answer (score 0):

You may need to ensure that the .confg file that is being written to has correct permissions.

Try running your Nvidia settings settings as Root with the `sudo` command, or changing the permissions of the file to suit the user you wish to access the file.

Comment: I do run it as root. I don't exactly know where the files are usually saved. I'm a bit of a noob with linux

Comment: I dont know where the files are stored either.

Comment: perhaps see this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/379483/nvidia-x-server-settings-lost-on-every-reboot?rq=1