# Ubuntu desktop freezes sometimes

Tags: freeze, desktop-environments

After having installed Ubuntu 14.10 freshly, I still have the same error that I already had in 14.04 and 12.04. The desktop sometimes just freezes. To use the desktop again I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to basically reload the desktop. I tried around a bit, installing **Unity**, **KDE4**, **Gnome 3**, **Mate**, **Cinnamon**, **xfce**, and I get the same error with all desktops. I still can continue my work, but  it is truely annoying and I believe I am not the only one out there having this problem.

I already did some research, but have not found anything helpful.

My laptop is a Dell XPS with a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU and an NVIDIA GF116M [GeForce GT 555M/635M].

Is anybody familiar with this apparent bug?

[EDIT]:

The output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
        Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0571]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF116M [GeForce GT 555M/635M] [10de:124d] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Dell GeForce GT 555M [1028:0571]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: are you using proprietary driver? add the output `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`

Comment: I used the recommended driver that is offered after the installation by the desktop environment. (Edit above)

Comment: run in terminal `prime-select nvidia` and then `prime-select query` to check if it says `nvidia` and reply. Also you might wanna look here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: I think you're correct to suspect something hardware/graphics driver related since the bug shows up in different OS versions. Apparently you have a hybrid graphics system with an Intel and an Nvidia GPU. You might want to try the Bumblebee Project: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyEnglish and atmelino for your answers. Bumblebee provided the answer to me. I answered to my posting and will mark it as the adequate answer in 17h from now on.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04/549916#549916

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is in [wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee).

Easily done by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Had same issue with propiertary drivers. Bumblebee did the trick. Install primus aswell..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and searching on google I found that was due to multiple nvidia driver versions installed. Unfortunately I didn't find the thread, but it was something close to [Nvidia proprietary driver hangs/freezes/blank screen at login in 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417862/nvidia-proprietary-driver-hangs-freezes-blank-screen-at-login-in-13-10)

I downloaded the right driver from the Nvidia website, then I removed all the nvidia drivers installed on my system, reboot, got a console and installed the driver just downloaded. Perhaps you should even reinstall the kernel package after installing the nvidia driver